# Openmaptiles - Created own map server integrate with leaflet library

Tags: leaflet, openmaptiles

I am new to openmaptiles. Actually, I want to buy a package and create my own map tile server where I could fetch and display the map from my own server. But before that, I want to understand that how to create my own map server and display the map by using leaflet library.

So I followed the 'Docker' way to download the map free version and deployed it. But I do not know how to integrate with leaflet library. I read the documentation, But I was not able to understand.

Question 1: Can someone explain to me how to integrate created tile server with leaflet library?

Question 2: How to run docker command with explicitly specify which mbtiles to use?

```
 'docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server openmaptiles-2017-07-03_planet_z0_z14.mbtiles'.
```

I tried above command. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to run the command is, install docker first: [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows)

As docker will help to run the example and see everything working together on your pc, the real understanding of your question is that you want to have a server that can serve .mbtiles to your remote application, for that I have setup php server which are cheaper then nodejs hosts: [.mbtiles Server PHP](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/host/tileserver-php/)